# Connect Teams chat with external chat application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have an external chat application and I want to try integrate my chat application with MS Teams. I want to have the same type of chat service where MS Teams and Skype interoperate.
I need to know how this was done and is it possible that this can be achieved via API.
If yes, what are the steps? I don't have the idea on where I can start.

Comment: Haven't you asked the same question now 4 times?

Comment: Could you please let us know if these Graph APIs help - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chat?view=graph-rest-1.0,      https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Hi Meghana.. Thanks for the documents.. So what we really trying to achieve is as below.. Our Platform (agent) > MS Teams (user) > End User (contact).. so at the moment our client is using MS Teams (user) to contact the end client via Skype.. they want to use our platform as agent to communicate directly to Skype end users through MS Teams user account.. so we are trying a way to import the MS Teams chat/user to our platform to communicate with their end users using our platform.. please l assist

Comment: This question is being tracked here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72297772/connect-microsoft-teams-chat-with-other-chat-service